# Socket doesn't respond

Tags: java, android, node.js, sockets, networking

I am trying to do an android application using node.js server. In android code, socket.emit functions works well. However emit listenner(socket.on) doesn't respond. Android code is as follows;

```
private Emitter.Listener getbrowser1f = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
            //I want this place work. but it doesnt
        }
    };
```

function doesn't respond.
I am triggering getbrowser1 using this code on android,

```
socket.emit("getbrowser1","msg1");
```

related app.js code is as follows

```
socket.on('getbrowser1', function (data) {
    io.sockets.emit('getbrowser1f', a );
});
```

In javascript, I could easly use

```
socket.on('getbrowser1f' function(data){

});
```

and it works well but in android this is not the correct way to code it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after I made change in emit listener as in following code;

```
        socket.on("getbrowser1f", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                Log.d(TAG, "object.event");
                socket.emit("doit2","msg2");
            }
        });
```